# Why not resolved type for argument of function, which element of object (typescript)?

Tags: typescript

Anyone can help me?
This is 3 examples: a, b, c. For first and second "arg" type is true (number). For third version typescript can't resolve type for "arg".

```
function a<T extends (value: number) => string>(
    arg: T,
) {
    return null;
}

a((arg) => arg.toExponential()); // ARG HAS RIGHT TYPE: number

function b<T extends { [index: string]: (value: number) => string }>(
    arg: T,
) {
    return null;
}
b({ x: (arg) => arg.toExponential() }); // ARG HAS RIGHT TYPE: number

function c<K extends { [index: string]: number }, T extends {[P in keyof K]?: ((value: number) => string) }>(
    arg1: K,
    arg2: T,
) {
    return null;
}
c({ x: 15 }, { x: (arg) => arg.toExponential() }); // ARGS NOT HAS TYPE: any
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler gets a bit confused when the two type parameters have a dependency and one needs to be inferred dependent on the other. A simple work around I use is to do a two step call, the first function fixes the first argument type and the second call can have the rest of the type inferred:

```
function c<K extends { [index: string]: number }>(arg1: K)
{
    return function <T extends {[P in keyof K]?: ((value: number) => string) }>(arg2: T){
    };
}


c({ x: 15 })({ x: (arg) => arg.toExponential() }); // arg will be number
```

**Edit**

Although the above solution works and correctly infers `T`, as suggested by @MihailMalostanidis, it might not be necessary in this case to use the second parameter at all. This also infers correctly:

```
function c<K extends { [index: string]: number } >(
    arg1: K,
    arg2: {[P in keyof K]?: ((value: number) => string) },
)  {
    return null;
}
```

The difference is that if you were to return `arg2` from the function (or a type based on `T`), in this version all keys of `K` would be present, not just those actually specified in `arg2` when called. Depending on your use case, this may be acceptable, but the initial solution is applicable in all cases.

Comment: What a tragedy.
Interesting to note that the following works:

 function c<K extends {[index: string]: number}>(
  arg1: K,
  arg2: {[P in keyof K]?: ((value: number) => string)},
 ) {}

It's only when it's put into a type variable that it breaks.

Do you know if there's an issue tracking this problem on the TypeScript repo?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis Yes you are right and maybe in this case that is sufficient, I went straight to my full solution for the problem. I will add your observation to the answer. 10x

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank, I didn't think of that limitation, [but it appears that it actually passes it on, even if the function is imported in another file!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20c%3CK%20extends%20%7B%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%7D%3E(%0A%09arg1%3A%20K%2C%0A%09arg2%3A%20%7B%5BP%20in%20keyof%20K%5D%3F%3A%20((value%3A%20number)%3D%3Estring)%7D%2C%0A)%20%7B%0A%09return%20arg2%0A%7D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20c(%7B%20x%3A%205%20%7D%2C%7Bx%3A%20a%3D%3E''%2Ba%7D)%0Aa.x%0Aa.y)

Comment: Furthermore, it's possible to once again use the keys using the good old `const renamed: {[P in keyof typeof arg2]?: typeof arg2[P]} = arg2
` operator :D